# Big values for Hash Match with this query ( Lots of sub selects )

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having problem to run this query.

```
SELECT  
    JROS.ID_DATA_JMTM, 
    JROS.ID_CEL_JMTM,
    JROS.TXM,
    JROS.DATA,  
    JROS.NO_COL_JMTM,
    MDU.QT_PRAZODIASU,
    MDU.CD_RENDA_FIXA,
    MDU.VL_FUTURO,
    MDU.DT_REF_TRANS,
    MDU.FIXING,
    0.00 AS "VL_MTM",
    MDU.TIPO
    FROM 
    (SELECT
    B.ID_DATA_JMTM, 
    B.ID_CEL_JMTM,
    (B.VL_MTM*FTR1+C.VL_MTM*FTR2)/DENOM AS TXM,
    B.DATA,
    B.ID_COL_JMTM,
    B.FATOR + CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.DU) AS NO_COL_JMTM

FROM(   SELECT 
        DU,SUBSTRING(NO_COL_JMTM,1,3)as NO_COL_JMTM,VERT1,PAR_FIM as VERT2,
            (PAR_FIM-DU) AS FTR1,(DU-VERT1) AS FTR2,PAR_FIM-VERT1 AS DENOM
        FROM PARAMETRO_MTM P
        ,(  SELECT DISTINCT CASE RISCO_JUROS 
            WHEN 'N' THEN 'PRE'+ CAST( QT_PRAZODIASU AS varchar(17) )  
            ELSE NO_COL_JMTM 
            END AS NO_COL_JMTM ,QT_PRAZODIASU AS DU
            FROM RENDA_FIXA_MDU A      WITH (NOLOCK) 
            WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(NO_COL_JMTM)) <> ''                                                                                                                                     
         ) VALOR
       WHERE DU>=VERT1 AND DU<PAR_FIM
    ) A,
    (   
    SELECT 
    DT_JMTM AS DATA,
    SUBSTRING(NO_COL_JMTM,1,3) AS FATOR,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(NO_COL_JMTM,4,4) AS INT) AS VERT,
    VL_MTM ,
    B.ID_DATA_JMTM,
    C.ID_CEL_JMTM ,
    A.ID_COL_JMTM
        FROM JUROS_MTM A
        ,JUROS_MTM_DATA B
        ,JUROS_MTM_CEL C 
        WHERE A.ID_COL_JMTM = C.ID_COL_JMTM 
        AND B.ID_DATA_JMTM = C.ID_DATA_JMTM 
        AND DT_JMTM  between cast('2016-02-01' as date) and cast('2016-04-13' as date)
    ) B,
    (   SELECT DT_JMTM AS DATA,SUBSTRING(NO_COL_JMTM,1,3) AS FATOR,CAST(SUBSTRING(NO_COL_JMTM,4,4) AS INT) AS VERT,VL_MTM ,B.ID_DATA_JMTM,C.ID_CEL_JMTM ,A.ID_COL_JMTM
        FROM JUROS_MTM A
        ,JUROS_MTM_DATA B
        ,JUROS_MTM_CEL C
        WHERE A.ID_COL_JMTM = C.ID_COL_JMTM 
        AND B.ID_DATA_JMTM = C.ID_DATA_JMTM 
        AND DT_JMTM  between cast( '2016-02-01' as date) and cast('2016-04-13' as date) 
    ) C

WHERE A.NO_COL_JMTM = B.FATOR 
AND A.NO_COL_JMTM = C.FATOR 
AND B.VERT = A.VERT1
AND C.VERT = CASE WHEN A.DU >= 2600 THEN 2600 ELSE A.VERT2 END 
AND B.ID_DATA_JMTM = C.ID_DATA_JMTM 
) JROS
INNER JOIN RENDA_FIXA_MDU MDU
ON MDU.NO_COL_JMTM = JROS.NO_COL_JMTM
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, because I want to select `between 2017 / 2016'` for exmaple, but it's taking 2 minutes to list 1 month ( After I add an index on `JUROS_MTM_DATA ( DT_JMTM) include (ID_DATA_JMTM)`

This is the query plan ( part of it ):

[image]

coudn't solve the problem [with this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221373/sql-server-query-performance-removing-need-for-hash-match-inner-join).

Probably, using `SQL Sentry`, the Merge Join ( table - renda_fixa_mdu) has `EST ROWS` is 50millions

Comment: The problem you're likely running into is that the data in the derived tables isn't persisted anywhere, so the functions you're running on columns (like substring) and then checking against predicates are going to perform poorly. They're not SARGable, in other words. I'd try dumping stuff out to #temp tables.

Comment: Huum Thanks Again Erik. I will make some updates in the query.

Comment: Holy jesus I just changed the first select, to a #temp1. It' running in 4 seconds. It was 15minutes before.